# Busy Indicator CSS

Tags: html, css

I am creating a busy indicator for my widget

I need help to make the Circle to also shimmer

Link to the code:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/rhdew1pc/109/`
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are fan of CSS animations (like me) I highly recommend checking out the various animations you can easily generate in a second with these tools:

http://animista.net/

http://www.theappguruz.com/tag-tools/web/CSSAnimations/

http://angrytools.com/css/animation/

I would personally do something like this:

```css
.pulsate-bck{-webkit-animation:pulsate-bck .5s ease-in-out infinite both;animation:pulsate-bck .5s ease-in-out infinite both}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate-bck{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1)}50%{-webkit-transform:scale(.9);transform:scale(.9)}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1)}}@keyframes pulsate-bck{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1)}50%{-webkit-transform:scale(.9);transform:scale(.9)}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1)}}

@-webkit-keyframes placeHolderShimmer {
    0% {
      background-position: -468px 0
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 468px 0
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes prideShimmer {
    from {
      background-position: top left
    }
    to {
      background-position: top right
    }
  } 

.animated-background {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    background: #fff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #d8d8d8 0%, #fff 20%, #d8d8d8 40%, #fff 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 9OOpx 1O4px;
    height: 275px;
    position: relative;
  }

.dot {
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #fff;
    content: '';
    height: 180px;
    left: 105px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    width: 179.80px;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center center, #D8D8D8 24%, #D8D8D8 31%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  } 

.white1{
    border-radius: 0%;
    /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff; */
    content: '';
    height: 20px;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    /* width: 305px; */
    background: radial-gradient(#fff, #fff);
}
.white2{
    border-radius: 0%;
    /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff; */
    content: '';
    height: 6px;
    left: 410px; right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 220px;
    /* width: 305px; */
    background: radial-gradient(#fff, #fff);
}
.white3{
    border-radius: 0%;
    /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff; */
    content: '';
    height: 13px;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 226px;
    /* width: 200px; */
    background: radial-gradient(#fff, #fff);
}
.white4{
    border-radius: 0%;
    /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff; */
    content: '';
    height: 6px;
    left: 440px; right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 239px;
    /* width: 200px; */
    background: radial-gradient(#fff, #fff);
}
.white5{
    border-radius: 0%;
    /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff; */
    content: '';
    height: 13px;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 245px;
    /* width: 200px; */
    background: radial-gradient(#fff, #fff);
}
.white6{
    border-radius: 0%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff;
    content: '';
    height: 6px;
    left: 178px; right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 258px;
    /* width: 200px; */
    background: radial-gradient(#fff, #fff); 
}
.white7{
    border-radius: 0%;
    /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff; */
    content: '';
    height: 13px;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 264px;
    /*width: 200px; */
    background: radial-gradient(#fff, #fff);
}
.c1{
    border-radius: 0%;
    /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff; */
    content: '';
    height: 200px;
    left: 0x; right: 200
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    /*dth: 200px; */
    background: radial-gradient(#fff, #fff);
}
.c2{
    border-radius: 0%;
    /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff; */
    content: '';
    height: 200px;
    left: 0; right: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    width: 100px;
    background: radial-gradient(#fff, #fff);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="animated-background">
<div class="dot pulsate-bck"></div> 
<div class="white1"></div>
<div class="white2"></div>
<div class="white3"></div>
<div class="white4"></div>
<div class="white5"></div>
<div class="white6"></div>
<div class="white7"></div>
<div class="c1"></div>
<div class="c2"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I really do appreciate your response and will study those references that you provided me. I would like to know if you can help make my code effects like this one https://codepen.io/oslego/pen/XdvWmd
Also, the circle should shimmer. Thanks a lot!